# 3 level dictionary python doesn't work obvious

Tags: python, dictionary, multi-level

```
>>> servers = ["srv1.usa", "srv1.lnd"]
>>> proxies = ["proxy1.usa", "proxy1.lnd"]
>>> proxy_map = {}.fromkeys(servers, {}.fromkeys(proxies, {}))
>>> print proxy_map
{'srv1.lnd': {'proxy1.lnd': {}, 'proxy1.usa': {}}, 'srv1.usa': {'proxy1.lnd': {}, 'proxy1.usa': {}}}
>>> proxy_map["srv1.lnd"]["proxy1.lnd"] = {"hosts": "host1.usa"}
>>> print proxy_map
{'srv1.lnd': {'proxy1.lnd': {'hosts': 'host1.usa'}, 'proxy1.usa': {}}, 'srv1.usa': {'proxy1.lnd': {'hosts': 'host1.usa'}, 'proxy1.usa': {}}}
```

That's my question, why python changed two dictionaries instead of one that I changed? Sorry, if this question is stupid, but I did not found answer for my case. Thank you!

Comment: The answers to the duplicate do not provide any good explations of _why_ this happens, which is what OP wants to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fromkeys` is a trap. Don't use it.

When you use `dict.fromkeys`, all values of the resulting dict are the same object. Not just equal objects - they're the same object. If you do `d = dict.fromkeys(keys, val)`, anything you do to `d[key1]` is visible through `d[key2]`, because `d[key1]` and `d[key2]` are the same thing.

`dict.fromkeys` is usually only useful when the values are immutable. The rest of the time, you should use a dict comprehension to reevaluate the value expression for each key. For example,

```
{key: {} for key in keys}
```

instead of `dict.fromkeys(keys, {})`.

Comment: Thank you, that what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions is to use dictionary comprehension:

Instead of `proxy_map = {}.fromkeys(servers, {}.fromkeys(proxies, {}))`

use

`proxy_map = {server : {proxy: {} for proxy in proxies} for server in servers}`

Complete example:

```
>>> servers = ["srv1.usa", "srv1.lnd"]
>>> proxies = ["proxy1.usa", "proxy1.lnd"]
>>> proxy_map = {server : {proxy: {} for proxy in proxies} for server in servers}
>>> proxy_map
{'srv1.usa': {'proxy1.usa': {}, 'proxy1.lnd': {}}, 'srv1.lnd': {'proxy1.usa': {}, 'proxy1.lnd': {}}}
>>> proxy_map["srv1.lnd"]["proxy1.lnd"] = {"hosts": "host1.usa"}
>>> proxy_map
{'srv1.usa': {'proxy1.usa': {}, 'proxy1.lnd': {}}, 'srv1.lnd': {'proxy1.usa': {}, 'proxy1.lnd': {'hosts': 'host1.usa'}}}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is it, thank you for the working example.

Comment: So please accept it as the right answer